# getting the parameters of the fit curve in Seaborn distplot when the fit parameter is not passed

Tags: python, parameters, seaborn, curve-fitting

I am using Seaborn distplot

```
Seaborn.distplot(a = my_data)
```

. Notice I do not specify fit parameter or any other parameter. As a result, I get the histogram of my_data (with number of  bins automatically assigned by Seaborn) and a curve fitted to the histogram.

[image]

Now, my question is how to get the parameters of the fit curve? distplot just returns the ax which I am assuming does have the points on the fit curve and not the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve you see is a kernel density estimate (KDE) of the data. You cannot get any parameters out of seaborn, but there aren't that many parameters for a gaussian KDE anyways. The only free parameter is the bandwidth, which is also set by seaborn to default to "scott".

```
import statsmodels.nonparametric.api as smnp
kde = smnp.KDEUnivariate(data)
x,y = kde.fit("gau", "scott", "gau", gridsize=100, cut=3, clip=None)
```